# Error in AJAX form submit using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting Error in submitting the form using AJAX and Jquery, following is the code i'm using to submit the form.

```
function formControl() {
    $('form#form_contact').submit(function(){
        if (verifyErrors()) {
            action = $(this).attr('action');
            mesagetosend = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'mailscript/smtpmail.php',
                    data: mesagetosend,
                    dataType : "html",
                    timeout:10000,
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert("Error:="+msg);
                        onerrormsg(msg);
                    },
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert("Success:="+msg);
                        onsuccessmsg(msg); 
                    }
                });
            }
        return false;
    });
}
```

in alert i'm getting `"Error:=[object XMLHttpRequest]"`

do anyone have any idea, why it returns error???

Comment: use `console.log(msg);` instead of `alert("Error:="+msg);` with google Chrome browser to get a better debug message

Comment: thankx dotoree, will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becuase you're printing the whole object. The error function actually returns three arguments:

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

Do it like this instead:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("Status:="+textStatus + " Error:="+errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: Status:=Timeout Error:= Undefined

Answer (score 0):

The parameter being sent to your error handler is an XHR object. Log it to the console to inspect its values. From there you should see the status code and possible errors.

```
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: now, i have changed my code to  `error: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      onerrormsg(msg);
     },
     success: function(msg){
      console.log(msg);
      onsuccessmsg(msg); 
     }` now my question is, where the message will displayed, what does the console.log(msg) do??